# Как проверить существование данных из foreach в базе MySQL по имени таблицы?

Tags: php, mysqli

Делаю выборку из базы, проверяю отсутствует ли таблица $symbol в базе данных и если отсутствует, то добавляю ее и параллельно вношу информацию о ней в отдельную таблицу symbol.

```
foreach($data as $values) {

$symbol = strtolower($values['symbol']);  



$sql = "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$symbol'";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

if (!empty($result->num_rows)){}else{
   // Добавляю новую таблицу в базу и далее наполняю ее данными

     $sql = "CREATE TABLE  `$symbol` (...

     $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO `symbol`...

}


}
```

Получается на мой взгляд слишком нагружено и вроде бы долго выполняется.

В базе есть отдельная таблица symbol со всеми имеющимися $symbol

Можно как-то на основе этой таблицы выполнять проверку, т.е. полностью изменить имеющуюся у меня функцию выше?

Так я могу получить список всех $symbol

```
$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT name FROM symbol");

// Получаю список всех $symbol
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {

// КАК ЗДЕСЬ ДОБАВИТЬ ОТСУТСТВУЮЩУЮ ТАБЛИЦУ $symbol, 
// как определить что в foreach($data as $values) ее еще нет? 

$symbol = $result["name"];

print $symbol . '<br />';

}
```

Надеюсь понятно описано, спасибо!

p.s. Меня смущает этот код, кажется не верным в моей задаче

```
foreach($data as $values) {

   $symbol = strtolower($values['symbol']);  

   $sql = "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$symbol'";

   $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);


      if (!empty($result->num_rows)){}else{
       ...
      }
}
```

Получается, если в базе данных 1000 таблиц, то этот скрипт будет обходить их все по очереди в поисках отсутствующей таблицы. Зачем это делать если как-то можно сравнить предварительно получив данные из таблицы symbol и не обходить всю базу данных.

Comment: XY-problem. Соответственно первейший вопрос - а задача-то какая? Что Вы собрались делать - понятно, а вот нафига? Ну и - в процессе решения оно реально надо получать "список всех $symbol"? или Вы хотите их получить только для того, чтобы сравнить и сразу забыть? если так - то получать их ну совершенно не нужно. А вообще у MySQL для решения задачи "добавить в таблицу отсутствующие значения" есть куча средств - INSERT IGNORE, INSERT .. ODKU, REPLACE INTO...

Comment: Опять - это не задача, а выбранный для её решения путь. Сразу скажу - путь скорее всего неверный.

Comment: $sql = "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$symbol'"; работает, но мне он кажется не верным, так как по всей базе ищется $symbol, зачем его искать построчно во всей базе, когда разом можно получить данные из таблицы symbol И КАК-ТО СРАВНИТЬ С ПОЛУЧЕННЫМИ В foreach($data as $values) ДАННЫМИ...

Comment: Я хочу получить $symbol чтобы сравнить и найти те, которых еще нет в базе. Если найду, то добавить найденные в базу. Если в базе нет $symbol, то для него создается отдельная таблица symbol (CREATE TABLE) и далее в нее вносится информация. REPLACE INTO не подходит для данной задачи.

Comment: Всё это MySQL сделает самостоятельно, нет никакой необходимости волочь что-то с сервера в программу на PHP и обратно.

Comment: Постоянно выполнять CREATE TABLE даже если таблица уже есть в базе данных, так получается?

Comment: @НатальяЮрова "Постоянно выполнять CREATE TABLE даже если таблица уже есть в базе данных, так получается?" ---  для этого есть например есть CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS

Comment: Почитаю, спасибо!

Comment: *для этого есть например есть CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS* Как паллиатив сойдёт...

Comment: Вы что, пытаетесь переизобрести миграции? Они в фрейворках уже есть: [Симфони](https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/current/index.html), [Лара](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations). Не используете это? Посмотрите [пакеты](https://packagist.org/?query=migrations). Не разбираетесь ни в чем из этого? Тогда разберитесь, оно того стоит. Хотя бы посмотрите сорцы и сделайте свою поделку аналогичным способом

Comment: Гляну, спасибо! CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS очень интересно, в связке с REPLACE INTO должно работать даже продуктивнее. Буду все переписывать и тестировать... Спасибо!

Comment: выберите существующие таблицы из `information_schema.tables` то?  Я так понимаю, что у вас в таблице `symbol`  содержатся имена интересующих таблицы. напишите джойн запрос и получите список отсутствующих.

Answer (score 0):

Следующий запрос даст вам перечень таблиц/представлений, которые отсутствуют в БД

```
SELECT name
FROM symbol AS s
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables AS t ON (
      t.table_name = s.name
      AND t.table_schema = 'your_db_name' 
   )
WHERE t.table_name IS NULL
```

*зы: Вообще все это наверное имеет смысл в хранимку вытащить*

Comment: Буду тестировать, спасибо.